# Scrapy spider returns no items data

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

My scrapy script seems not to follow links, which ends up not extracting data from each of them (to pass some content as scrapy `items`).

I am trying to scrape a lot of data from a news website. I managed to copy/write a spider that, as I assumed, should read links from a file (I've generated it with another script), put them in `start_urls` list and start following these links to extract some data, and then pass it as `items`, and also -- write each item's data in a separate file (last part is actually for another question).

After running `scrapy crawl PNS`, script goes through all the links from `start_urls` but does nothing more -- it follows links read from `start_urls` list (I'm getting "GET link" message in bash), but seems not to enter them and read some more links to follow and extract data from.

```
import scrapy
import re
from ProjectName.items import ProjectNameArticle

class ProjectNameSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'PNS'

    allowed_domains = ['www.project-domain.com']

    start_urls = []

    with open('start_urls.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            start_urls.append(line.strip())

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('div.news-wrapper_ h3.b-item__title a').xpath('@href').extract():
            # extracted links look like this: "/document.html"
            link = "https://project-domain.com" + link
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_news)

    def parse_news(self, response):

        data_dic = ProjectNameArticle() 

        data_dic['article_date'] =  response.css('div.article__date::text').extract_first().strip()
        data_dic['article_time'] =  response.css('span.article__time::text').extract_first().strip()
        data_dic['article_title'] = response.css('h3.article__title::text').extract_first().strip()
        news_text =  response.css('div.article__text').extract_first()
        news_text =  re.sub(r'(<script(\s|\S)*?<\/script>)|(<style(\s|\S)*?<\/style>)|(<!--(\s|\S)*?-->)|(<\/?(\s|\S)*?>)', '', news_text).strip()
        data_dic['article_text'] = news_text
        return data_dic
```

Expected result:

> 1. Script opens start_urls.txt file, reads its lines (every line contains a single link), puts these links to `start_urls` list,
> 2. For each link opened spider extracts deeper links to be followed (that's about 50-200 links for each `start_urls` link),
> 3. Followed links are the main target from which I want to extract specific data: article title, date, time, text.
> 4. For now never mind writing each scrapy item to a distinc .txt file.

Actual result:

> 1. Running my spider triggers GET for each `start_urls` link, goes through around 150000, doesn't create a list of deeper links, nor enters them to extract any data.

Comment: Have you tried printing something in the parse function ?
`print(response.css('div.news-wrapper_ h3.b-item__title a').xpath('@href').extract())` for example

Comment: To debug your code you can also use the `inspect_response()` function.
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses

Then you can try to see if your css path is correct

Comment: @Sewake, I've tried to open one of the `start_urls` via `scrapy shell url-goes-here`. Then to read list of new urls (leading to specific articles), and I've discovered that `response.css('div.news-wrapper_ h3.b-item__title a').xpath('@href').extract()` is returning this: `http://project-domain.com/document.html?id=0000`, but, when hovered in a browser, it's actually `http://project-domain.com/document.html?id=0000&cid=1111`. I need a bit of RegEx not to omit stuff after `&`?

Comment: Never mind. Some of these links have this "&cid=1111" part, some of them don't. So this is not the problem. Script reads both of them properly. But doesn't "enter" them.

Comment: Maybe this is my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922218/scrapy-spider-not-following-links?rq=1, but I'm not sure what "I needed to subclass `CrawlSpider` rather than `Spider`" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dude, I have been coding in Python Scrapy for long time and I hate using `start_urls`

You can simply use `start_requests` which is very easy to read, and also very easy to learn for beginners

```
class ProjectNameSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'PNS'

    allowed_domains = ['www.project-domain.com']

    def start_requests(self):

        with open('start_urls.txt', 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                yield Request(line.strip(), 
                    callback=self.my_callback_func)

    def my_callback_func(self, response):
        for link in response.css('div.news-wrapper_ h3.b-item__title a').xpath('@href').extract():
            # extracted links look like this: "/document.html"
            link = "https://project-domain.com" + link
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_news)

    def parse_news(self, response):

        data_dic = ProjectNameArticle() 

        data_dic['article_date'] =  response.css('div.article__date::text').extract_first().strip()
        data_dic['article_time'] =  response.css('span.article__time::text').extract_first().strip()
        data_dic['article_title'] = response.css('h3.article__title::text').extract_first().strip()
        news_text =  response.css('div.article__text').extract_first()
        news_text =  re.sub(r'(<script(\s|\S)*?<\/script>)|(<style(\s|\S)*?<\/style>)|(<!--(\s|\S)*?-->)|(<\/?(\s|\S)*?>)', '', news_text).strip()
        data_dic['article_text'] = news_text
        return data_dic
```

I also have never used `Item` class and find it useless too

You can simply have `data_dic = {}` instead of `data_dic = ProjectNameArticle()`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it today. So in my case "my_callback_func" would be "parse", right? Or "parse_news"?

Comment: You can name it whatever you want

Comment: Yes, I know. I mean, I have two functions: first to parse urls generated with `start_requests()`, this is -- "parse" function, and second -- to parse internal links, this is -- "parse_news". So except for "start_requests" function, everything else stays as it was? First `parse()` and then `parse_news()` called inside `parse()`?

Comment: @DanielBorysowski yes you are right, and to avoid any confusion, I have edited my answer with your full code, please see my answer again

Comment: Hmm, it does the same -- nothing. I've noticed this line in the `scrapy crawl PNS` output: `2019-01-30 19:03:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: []`. I haven't mentioned that I am a Scrapy newbie, and that's why I haven't put anything in the pipelines.py file; should I? Because now it's returning empty list. Dunno if it's relevant. I could paste full bash output here, but that's 66 lines. It shows some GET messages for `start_urls`, then 1 of the inner links (of around 200 of them), and closes the spider.

Comment: OK. It works. The problem was `allowed_domains`. I've set it to `www.project-domain.com`, while actually was trying to scrape data from `https://project-domain.com`. Anyway, I've figured it out thanks to @Sewake's `inspect_response()` tip, and also all of @Umair's advices. Thank you guys.